# Bootstrap Nav is justified, but not aligned to the top. How do i fix that?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

see:

http://shfa.designbytricia.com/

I have gotten the nav to be justified, but it leaves a space above it (for the mobile nav container). How can I have be both justified and not leave that space above it?

I've tried everything I can think of, but the only thing that fixes it, is to remove the:

```
 .navbar .nav li {
   width: 1%
 }
```

which also removes the justification.

So again how can I have the justification, but get rid of that extra space up top. There should be NO space. Just the nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra margin on your `nav_main_row` class, just change your CSS to this:

```
.nav_main_row {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Comment: that worked, but it also brought up the mobile version of the nav -30px. But that's ok as I can isolate it via a media query to only use it on the sizes above mobile. And in my case it actually looks pretty good having the mobile menu over the nav, so I might just keep it globally. Thanks!